# PHP Form $_POST['button'] always false

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get submit form event to update a field. I found a test code on internet and that's worked. But when I change the button name for my button nothing happens, and the if always returns false to my button and I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Example code works:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="add" Value="Call Add fun">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" Value="Call Sub funn">
<?php echo @$a; ?>
<?php
if(@$_POST['add'])
{
    function add()
    {
        $a="You clicked on add fun";
        echo $a;
    }
    add();
} else if (@$_POST['sub']) {
    function sub()  
    {
        $a="You clicked on sub funn";
        echo $a;  
    }
    sub();  
}
?>
```

I've tried some variations with if (isset($_POST["course_submit_btn"])) but again nothin happens.

I don't know if it has any interface, but the page url is "panel/create-course/?course_ID=3493/"

My page https://www.file.io/c0pn/download/C1kmP2TblfcU

Comment: While it is legal to define funtions inside an IF it is dangerous to do it. If you dont enter the IF the function wont exists. Instead define the functions at the top of the script

Comment: PS Most of us will not follow links from strangers, so instead paste code or error messages into the question as text

Comment: That's a terrible example of code and you shouldn't try to learn from it. That said, it does do what it is supposed to do. I've tested it and I cannot reproduce the problem you are having. My best guess is that [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-but-the-code-shows-in-the-browser-source-code?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: `$_POST["course_submit_btn"]` You dont have a field with the name `course_submit_btn` Please try and make your questions make some sense

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly  of course I have. Did you see the file on link? The issue is that the if is executed for the example code (just a example) and not for the form <form action="" id="tutor-frontend-course-builder" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="edit_course">.

Comment: Just for your edification, I have enough reps to allow me to see the edits you have made :)

Comment: Oh and the answer is NO, as all I get from the link is `There was an error retrieving your file.`

Comment: PS Most of us wont follow links posted by strangers, for obvious reasons, and it is suggested by the site that you do not post links to off site resources for that very reason amongst others

Comment: for a moment I thought I wrote the wrong field, but I went back. If you didn't look at the code in the link (which is too long to post here) I don't even know why you bothered to reply.

Comment: Code to long to post? Then read the requirement for [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: in fact to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="add" Value="Call Add fun">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" Value="Call Sub fun">

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        add();
    } else if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
        sub();
    }

    function add() {
        echo "You clicked on add fun";
        // todo: more meaningful functionality
    }

    function sub() {
        echo "You clicked on sub fun";
        // todo: more meaningful functionality
    }
?>
```

Your code should work, however there are some tips, you should stick to:

1. Use consistent code styling (spaces, brackets etc),
2. Use more meaningful names, in a few days you won't know what variable $a is for
3. Don't put functions within if sections